# "zsh: illegal hardware instruction python" when installing Tensorflow on macbook pro M1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon

I'm trying to get tensorflow working on my MacBook pro M1. However, I keep getting the following error when trying to import: `zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python`

I have downloaded and installed tensorflow via this [link](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/releases/tag/v0.1alpha1).

These were my installation steps:

- install a venv: `python3 -m venv venv`.
- drag the `install_venv.sh` (which is located within the downloaded folder) file to the terminal, add `-p` at the end.
- select the directory of the venv as the location where tensorflow should be installed.
- activate the venv.
- type "python".
- try to import tensorflow: `import tensorflow as tf`.

I'm using Python 3.8.2.

Comment: You can follow this blog for the similar issue and try the same suggested solution from the thread https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-10-15-catalina-on-unsupported-macs.2183772/page-426. Also for latest update on tensorflow for mac OS you can follow this link https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/11/accelerating-tensorflow-performance-on-mac.html

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/72381925/2546381 worked!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This worked for me after trying a bunch of solutions to no avail.

Step 1 Using pyenv install python version 3.8.5 and set it as your default python version. This tutorial(https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) is helpful for
getting pyenv configured properly.

Step 1.1 Use this post(https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1446) if you have troubles running pyenv in zsh.

Step 1.2 Once you have python version 3.8.5 running which you can check by running `python -V` which should output:

```
Python 3.8.5
```

Step 2 Install virtualenv via `pip install virtualenv`

Step 2.1 Create a virtual environment by running `virtualenv ENV`

Step 2.2 Activate that virtual environment by running `source ENV/bin/activate`

Step 3 Install the tensorflow wheel called `tensorflow-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl` located at this public google drive link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1oSipZLnoeQB0Awz8U68KYeCPsULy_dQ7

Step 3.1  Assuming you simply installed the wheel to downloads run
`pip install ~/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl` in your activated virtual environment

Step 4 Type python which will bring up `>>>`in your terminal and type

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>>
```

If there is no 'zsh illegal hardware instruction" error you should be good to go.

Note: If you are using anaconda, the above will also work. You can skip the virtual env steps (assuming you have a virtual env activated through Conda) and just go straight to the `pip install` as mentioned above (steps 3 and later).

Comment: Apologies for the cyber awareness but how would one verify the affiliation/identity of the maintainer providing that wheel file from over google drive?

Comment: @matanster this is something I would also be wary of. In my case, it was such a pain to get it to run any other way so I went with this not optimal solution.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I have done this 3-4 times now and my computer has not been hacked : )

Comment: You may install tensorflow for M1 machines with this pip install command:  pip install tensorflow-macos

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Worked for me and wheel on google drive can be trusted :smile

Comment: Thanks a lot, I literally spent 3 days trying to resolve this issue. This us the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Python3 is shipped with 2 architectures in M1.

```sh
$ file $(which python3)
# If you installed python through Homebrew or Anaconda, deactivate your conda env, then run this line instead:
# $ file $(which /usr/bin/python3)
/usr/bin/python3: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/python3 (for architecture arm64e): Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

Here, it's very important to specify which one to use. You can do this by installing the script like this:

```sh
arch -arm64 bash install_venv.sh my_tf_env
```

if you have multiple python installations, use:

```sh
arch -arm64 bash install_venv.sh --python=/usr/bin/python3 my_tf_env
```

You can replace `my_tf_env` with any other name/path you choose.

Comment: When I run `$ file $(which python3)` I only get one option: `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/svc-pdf-reader/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64` Could this be a homebrew related issue?

Comment: First, deactivate your anaconda env if it's active. Then, change the line to `file $(which /usr/bin/python3)` and run it.

Comment: There's more than one `which` available in MacOS -- the one built into zsh, and the one shipped as an external binary. They're quite unlike each other; I generally don't recommend using `which` at all.

Comment: With all due respect, your comment has not added anything useful to the conversation at all.

Comment: Does this answer really mean that merely choosing the other python executable makes tensorflow seamlessly run as is?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue

This is because of M1 chip. Now there is a pre-release that delivers hardware-accelerated TensorFlow and TensorFlow Addons for macOS 11.0+. Native hardware acceleration is supported on M1 Macs and Intel-based Macs through Apple’s ML Compute framework.

You need to install the TensorFlow that supports M1 chip
Simply pull this [tensorflow macos repository](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos) and run the ./scripts/download_and_install.sh

Comment: ERROR: TensorFlow with ML Compute acceleration is only available on macOS 11.0 and later.