# “zsh: illegal hardware instruction python” when Tensorflow on macbook pro M1

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

I've followed every step of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook)

Install a venv: `python3 -m venv venv`.
drag the `install_venv.sh` (which is located within the downloaded folder) file to the terminal, add `-p` at the end.
select the directory of the venv as the location where tensorflow should be installed.
activate the venv.
type "python".

Try to import tensorflow: `import tensorflow as tf`.

I'm running my terminal not rosetta (which was the solution to the other problem):

```
(base) user@useros ~ % uname -m
arm64
```

When I activate my environment I still get:

```
(venv) (base) user@useros ~ % uname -m
arm64
```

If I run file `$(which python)` I get the following:
On base:

```
(base) user@useros ~ % file $(which python)
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

On venv:

```
(venv) (base) user@useros ~ % file $(which python)
/Users/user/venv/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Why do I get 'Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64' here even though I get 'arm64' before?
This confuses me and is probably the reason why my code is not working.

Comment: Because you're picking up a different Python installation. You can see it printed the path to the executable, and it changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Macbook pro M1, Tensorflow support is still ongoing.
Please take a look at this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46178#issuecomment-760392204).

Comment: Still not available. No wonder my Tensorflow vs Pytorch debate is not a thing anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating conda env with miniforge3 and install TensorFlow on the M1

[Tensorflow on Apple M1 Pro and M1 Max](https://www.mrdbourke.com/setup-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-max-for-machine-learning-and-data-science/)

If not interested in miniforge3 the following worked for me:

[tensorflow.org pip install instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/)