# Got this error message "zsh: illegal hardware instruction python3" when importing numpy on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, numpy

I am trying to import numpy after installing python 3 using pip install command on my new mac with OS Big Sur. When I try to import numpy I keep getting this error message--
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["zsh: illegal hardware instruction python" when installing Tensorflow on macbook pro M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook)