# Even after importing Numpy not recognised

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

My code:

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow
```

Output:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
< ipython-input-1-87dbf2ff9b36 > in < module >
----> 1 x = np.random.randint(0,100)

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

What I don't understand is that even though I have already imported the library it is not getting detected and gives me a NameError, Same is the case with a lot of libraries.

I am currently using Jupyter Lab through Anaconda.

=================================>

Got the solution for all the Issues while installing TensorFlow on **M1 Macbook**

Follow the below link:

[https://naturale0.github.io/machine%20learning/setting-up-m1-mac-for-both-tensorflow-and-pytorch#:~:text=Macs%20with%20ARM64%2Dbased%20M1,both%20from%20consumers%20and%20developers](https://naturale0.github.io/machine%20learning/setting-up-m1-mac-for-both-tensorflow-and-pytorch#:%7E:text=Macs%20with%20ARM64%2Dbased%20M1,both%20from%20consumers%20and%20developers).

Comment: What happens if you just import numpy without renaming it?

Comment: @Seppeke The problem still remains.

Comment: @Seppeke I have tried running the same on the terminal and looks like there is a problem there : I got this error ```zsh: Illegal hardware instruction python3```

Comment: What device are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook maybe this helps

Comment: @Seppeke I am using Macbook M1 Air

Comment: @Seppeke yes I have tried the solution in that but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Akella Niranjan for the reference. For the benefit of community providing solution here as written by @[Sihyung Park](https://github.com/naturale0).

**Install `TensorFlow-macOS` for Apple Silicon M1**

It is easy to install it with the system python since the installation script is given by Apple. However, my goal was to install it with other python so that I can install additional packages for data science without difficulty.

I mainly followed instructions from [here](https://laptrinhx.com/tensorflow-2-4-on-apple-silicon-m1-installation-under-conda-environment-2235153130/) to install tensorflow-macos, and then created ipykernel of it so that I can run this environment any time by switching the kernel inside jupyter notebook.

1. First [install miniforge, which natively supports M1](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download). The installation defaults to directory `~/miniforge3/.`
2. Create virtual environment named `tf_macos` with conda and install Python 3.8.

   ```
   conda create -n tf_macos
   conda activate tf_macos
   conda install -y python=3.8
   ```

I specified the version 3.8 so that it matches requirement of `tensorflow-macos`.

3. Download and install `tensorflow-macos` from [Apple Github](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos).

```
git clone https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos.git
cd tensorflow_macos/arm64
```

```
pip install --force pip==20.2.4 wheel setuptools cached-property six
pip install --upgrade --no-dependencies --force numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl grpcio-1.33.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl h5py-2.10.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl tensorflow_addons-0.11.2+mlcompute-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
pip install absl-py astunparse flatbuffers gast google_pasta keras_preprocessing opt_einsum protobuf tensorflow_estimator termcolor typing_extensions wrapt wheel tensorboard typeguard
pip install --upgrade --force --no-dependencies tensorflow_macos-0.1a1-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
```

4. Add the environment as jupyter kernel.

```
pip install jupyter
```

```
python -m ipykernel install --name=tf_macos
```

Then merely switching the ipython kernel to `tf_macos` allows us to use mlcompute-backend TensorFlow without a hassle

5. Install additional packages (optional)

```
conda install scipy pandas matplotlib
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://naturale0.github.io/machine%20learning/setting-up-m1-mac-for-both-tensorflow-and-pytorch)