# illegal hardware instruction

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to do this YouTube formation on TensorFlow : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U&t=7987s. At some step, I want to run the 'generate_tfrecord.py' with the following command :

```
python TensorFlow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py -x Tensorflow/workspace/images/train -l Tensorflow/workspace/annotations -o Tensorflow/workspace/annotations
```

in my terminal and I have this answer :

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python TensorFlow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py -x  -l  -o
```

and in Jupiter Notebook :

```
4348 Illegal instruction: 4
```

What can I do to avoid this and to just run the python file ?
I'm working on Mac OS Monterey on a M1 Macbook.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A related question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook