# python cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I have this code:

```
class CamThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, previewname, camid):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.previewname = previewname
        self.camid = camid

    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.previewname)
        previewcam(self.previewname, self.camid)

# Function to preview the camera.
def previewcam(previewname, camid):
    cv2.namedWindow(previewname)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camid)
    if cam.isOpened():
        rval, frame = cam.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.imshow(previewname, frame)
        rval, frame = cam.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27:  # Press ESC to exit/close each window.
            break
    cv2.destroyWindow(previewname)
```

when I run my python file, I get this error:

```
    self.run()
  File "swann.py", line 17, in run
    previewcam(self.previewname, self.camid)
  File "swann.py", line 21, in previewcam
    cv2.namedWindow(previewname)
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code
Assertion failed: (NSViewIsCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay() != currentlyBuildingLayerTree), function NSViewSetCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay, file NSView.m, line 13477.
zsh: illegal hardware instruction
```

I've never used the `cv2` package before, so I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong. Could someone help me out?

Comment: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: @Jeppe yes a Mac.

Comment: Looks like maybe cv2 was not installed for the right architecture - this thread is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook

Comment: @Jeppe thanks for sharing. I'm not on M1 Mac, so it shouldn't apply to me...

Comment: @Jeppe incase your curious, downgrading the version of cv2 fixed it

Comment: Ah okay! Consider writing an answer with the bad/good versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue, see [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22602).
This is macOS specific problem, when cv2 tries to interact with UI in newly spawned thread, it throws this error. Use UI interactions on main thread only.