# How to solve zsh: illegal hardware instruction python manage.py makemigrations on mac, what is this error

Tags: python, django, macos, apple-m1

python manage.py makemigrations shows some error after the installation of pip install deepface

```
Error : zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python manage.py makemigrations
```

System info :OS - Ventura 13.O, Chip- M1

What is this issue, why this happen and how to solve it

Comment: I think you need to install deepface that supports M1 chip

Comment: I installed deepface using pip, is that version is not supported?

Comment: refer this https://github.com/chychkan/DeepFaceLab_MacOS

Comment: Same error solved here also refer this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook