# zsh: illegal hardware instruction python when Installing TensorFlow on macbook pro M2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having a problem when trying to import tensorflow. I am running python 3.8:

```
Python 3.8.13 (default, Oct 19 2022, 17:54:22) 
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I installed tensorflow 2.10 inside a conda enviroment:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

I imagine I am not installing the proper version of tensorflow for the M2? Any idea how to solve this?

Note: I have tried https://www.mrdbourke.com/setup-apple-m1-pro-and-m1-max-for-machine-learning-and-data-science/

and other options including ["zsh: illegal hardware instruction python" when installing Tensorflow on macbook pro M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook)

but no luck so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["zsh: illegal hardware instruction python" when installing Tensorflow on macbook pro M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried several options for the M1 (including that one) and no luck so far.

Comment: Please try by changing some settings in your system as mentioned in this [link](https://code2care.org/zsh/zsh-illegal-hardware-instructions-python-tenserflow-m1-mac)? or can Create a virtual environment with Python 3.8 in conda environment and then install tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow-aarch64`,`pip install tensorflow-macos`. Please check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) for more details in this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on a M2 Macbook and solved it by installing this dependency instead (also using venv):

```
pip install tensorflow-macos
```

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded and installed tensorflow via this link.

These were my installation steps:

- install a venv: `python3 -m venv venv`.
- drag the (which is located within the downloaded folder) file to the terminal, add at the end. `install_venv.sh-p`
- Select the directory of the venv as the location where tensorflow
  should be installed.
- activate the venv.
- type "python".
- try to import tensorflow: .`import tensorflow as tf`

I'm using Python 3.8.2.