# Mediapipe Installation Issue on Python 3.10

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, mediapipe

I am facing difficulty in installing mediapipe on Python 3.10. The error message shows that

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe

However, I have successfully installed it on Python 3.7, but when I run my program on this version, I encounter issues with the tensorflow module, and the error message states

> zsh: illegal hardware instruction python

Can you please provide me with some assistance on this issue? I'm using M1 Macbook Air

Comment: I suggest using python 3.9 or lower for a few more years while waiting that the libraries mature for the newer versions, you will find less bugs and a more stable experience. Is there any reason why you do not want to use Python 3.7?

Comment: like i said, tf doesn't work with python 3.7 for some reason.

Comment: Ah ok, if so I suggest this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383338/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-when-installing-tensorflow-on-macbook

Comment: What exactly did you install? Seems you installed a x86_64 version of mediapipe while you have an ARM processor.

Comment: Did you check the [setup guide for python](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/setup_python) and verify that you have the correct settings for install? It says you need to use a Rosetta terminal and pip >20.3

Answer (score 0):

try to installed tensorflow via this link.

These were my installation steps:

- install a venv: `python3 -m venv venv`.
- drag the (which is located within the downloaded folder) file to the terminal, add at the end. `install_venv.sh-p`
- Select the directory of the venv as the location where tensorflow
  should be installed.
- activate the venv.
- type "python".
- try to import tensorflow: .`import tensorflow as tf`

I'm using Python 3.8.2.