# Error: Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

The Python interpreter just exits with:

> `"Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)".`

FYI here's my configuration:

OSX 11.1 (M1 MAC) /
PyCharm Pro (latest) /
Python 3.7 / tensorflow 2.2.0

Any idea on how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try to reinstall the various components (and maybe with newer versions). Check that you have Python and tensorflow with same CPU architecture: do no mix CPU: macos cannot run mixed code (either native M1, or just Intel, so translated with rosetta stone)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are [a few posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpycharm%5d%20exit%20code%20132) with this error for PyCharm. I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65242614) may help you. Try using the [search with tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) this kind of error is normally caused by a specific library incompatibility that you are using. There are also a number of [tensorflow posts with this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btensorflow%5Dexit+code+132).

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow does not support ARM yet. There is a alpha version on GitHub (r2.4rc0) with support for ARM  processors: https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos