# Jupyter Kernel Dies Importing Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, import

I am running an Apple Macbook with 16 GB of RAM and the M1 chip. I am trying to import Keras through the command:

`from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`  but all I am getting is the pop up that says

> Kernel Restarting
> The kernel for 02_Modeling.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Not sure how to fix this, not sure I've run Tensorflow on this computer before so don't know if this is a new thing but I can't fix it. Unsure of how to proceed.

When I run a python shell in terminal and try to import tensorflow I get this output:

> zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Open a python shell in the terminal and import tensorflow, it should also crash, then report the error message in your question.

Comment: This is the message that comes up



 zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3

Comment: See this question and answer, its literally the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132/65449643#65449643 Basically the problem is that you mixed architectures inside python.