# Kernel dead after importing Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, keras

I would like to make a LSTM forecasting using Keras.
Every time I run the prerequisite step: importing the library

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
```

the following message appears:

```
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

Same problem occurs when I:
`ìmport keras` or `import tensorflow`.

I am using MacOS version 11.2, 16 GB ram.

Comment: Import keras or tensorflow in a python terminal shell and report the error you get in your question.

Comment: zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python

Comment: ``import pandas` works. `Import keras` and `import tensorflow` result in that message.

Comment: If you are using an M1 Mac, then see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132/65449643#65449643 The problem is that you somehow installed a x86 library in an ARM python environment (or viceversa).

Answer (score 2):

If you using anaconda in MAC try

```
conda install -c conda-forge hdf5=1.10.5
```

If you using idle try

```
brew install hdf5=1.10.5
```

If above none of above solved. If you are using anaconda include this lines at the beginning

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
```

Comment: I created a virtualenv and run the code above, but got the message : "Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages."

Comment: Ok, Have you tried third set of code?. ..Add that couple of lines of code that are at 3rd step at the beginning of your code & Execute them.if you get same error please let me know