# Python shutdowns when I use Keras

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, keras

Before one day ago I try to Install Keras and Tensorflow on Anaconda Navigator and I think I made it. But I try to use Keras or Tensorflow it was shutdown when I run the code.

[image: Keras]
[image: Running code without Keras]
[image: Running code with Keras]

Please can someone help me for this problem?

Comment: Please provide more information, are you using a M1 Mac?

Comment: yes sir. Im using M1 MacBook Pro.

Comment: Its probably this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132/65449643#65449643 Basically you are mixing Intel and ARM libraries and that will not work, you need to make sure that only ARM libraries are being used. Not sure if Anaconda supports that.