# Kernel dying in juypter notebook

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, tf.keras

My kernel is dying everytime i run the following code. There is no error or anything so i dont know what is happening. I am running python 3.8.8 on the new macbook m1.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

Comment: Run this code in a python shell and it should also crash, then include the full error message in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I got illegal hardware so def the chip.

Comment: Do you mean illegal instruction? If yes please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132

Comment: no it was illegal hardware

Comment: The error message could be illegal hardware instruction, which is produced by Rosetta 2.

Comment: Thats true. I need to use the tensrflow for m1 chip.