# Are there problems with Tensorflow and Keras in Mac version 12.2 (OS Monterey)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I bought a new Mac version 12.2 (OS Monterey) and installed Anaconda. Most of the Python packages can be installed correctly. However, Tensorflow (ver 2.8.0) and Keras (ver 2.8.0) have major issues. The Jupyter notebook kernel gets killed when tensorflow and/or keras get imported. I looked up various posts on Stackoverflow and Medium, however, nothing seems helpful.  I even tried to convert the .ipynb to .py script, however, the same error occurs.

Is there anything that can be done to resolve this?

Comment: This has been asked and answered multiple times, you installed a x86_64 version of the libraries, while you need ARM versions.

Comment: For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132

Comment: Thank you!  Are you suggesting that I should install an earlier version of TensorFlow and Keras?  Some posts have suggested that.  

On another note, this "bug" should perhaps be reported to OS folks.

Comment: No, this is also not a bug, you need to install a version of TensorFlow (not Keras) that matches your CPU architecture. MacOS allows you to install Intel packages which run on top of Rosetta, but this does not work with TensorFlow because it uses AVX instructions.

Comment: I am still unable to install ARM versions of tensorflow.  Is there any particular way to do that?  I am not an expert on CPU architectures or Python, so some specific details will be of help.  Thank you for your time.