# LLDB exited unexpectedly when debug in vscode with CMake Tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, lldb, codelldb

I use macOS 14.1(23B2073) with Apple M3 Max, and I Create a cpp cmake project:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> some_vec_ptr; // set breakpoint at here
  return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(debug_test)

add_executable(debug_test main.cpp)
```

Then open the project in VSCode.
There are following VSCode extension has been installed:

1. C/C++ v1.19.2 Pre-Release
2. C/C++ Extension Pack v1.3.0
3. CMake v0.0.17
4. CMake Tools v1.17.14 Pre-Release
5. CodeLLDB v1.10.0

And when I use CMake Tools to debug the main.cpp, it exits with error code 0x84 (in VSCode DEBUG CONSONLE)

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=library-unloaded,id="/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test",target-name="/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test",host-name="/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test"
Loaded '/usr/lib/dyld'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test'. Symbols loaded.
=library-unloaded,id="/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test",target-name="/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test",host-name="/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test"
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_collections.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwindirectory.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/liboah.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
=thread-selected,id="1"
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)
ERROR: LLDB exited unexpectedly with exit code 132 (0x84). Debugging will now abort.
The program '/Users/intro/Spaces/TestSpace/CMake_Test/build/debug_test' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

My lldb-mi path is `/Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.19.2-darwin-arm64/debugAdapters/lldb-mi/bin/lldb-mi` and the version info is:

```
% /Users/xxx/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.19.2-darwin-arm64/debugAdapters/lldb-mi/bin/lldb-mi --version   
Version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4 
(This is a MI stub on top of LLDB and not GDB)
All rights reserved.
```

My lldb version info is:

```
% lldb --version
lldb-1500.0.200.58
Apple Swift version 5.9.2 (swiftlang-5.9.2.2.56 clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
```

My Clang++ version info is:

```
% clang++ --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

It will be normal after deleting `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> some_vec_ptr;`

My question is:

1. Where can I find the error code list of lldb?
2. What is the meaning of error code 132 (0x84).
3. Why debug with shared_ptr<vector<>> leads unexpectedly exit?

Comment: I think this question will help with #2: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242614/why-does-loading-tensorflow-on-mac-lead-to-process-finished-with-exit-code-132)

Comment: When programs crash on macOS, they dump a crash log for the crash in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports.  They are named with the name of the program that crashed followed by the crash time, and have the extension .ips.  They are JSON files, but if you open them in Console.app it will present a human-readable form.  That might give you some insight, and if you want to file a bug with either the llvm issues or Apple's feedback, it will help a lot if you include the crash report.

Comment: @JimIngham Thanks reply! There has no file with .ips extension in my ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports folder. All files in this folder has .diag extension. From what you said, these file names do contain timestamps, but they have nothing to do with VSCode debug. And there has no file in Retired folder.

Comment: It is possible for a parent process to suppress crash reports from their children.  It isn't a great idea (for just this reason) but maybe VSCode is doing that?  I don't know enough about VSCode to help there, however.

Comment: @JimIngham I didn't know about this method before seeing your comment, so thank you for providing a new way to solve the problem!